# Change legend position using holoviews / hvplot

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

Hvplot has default the position of the legend on the right outside of the plot. 
How can I change this default legend position?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv

data = np.random.normal(size=[50, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b'])
df.hvplot.line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change the legend position to top left by adding **.opts(legend_position='top_left')** to your code.

```
df.hvplot.line().opts(legend_position='top_left')
```

If you would like to position your legend **inside** your plot, you can choose from the following options:

> ['top_right', 'top_left', 'bottom_left', 'bottom_right']

If you want to place your legend **outside** your plot, you can choose from these options:

> ['right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom']

[image]